# How do you make use of the Android DeviceAdminSample.java code when there's no project

Tags: java, android

I want to run the Android SDK sample

ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/apis/app/DeviceAdminSample.java

But it's just a java file and nothing else; there's no project, no manifest, no layout files etc.

I could create a project from scratch and drop the java file into it but it seems like a lot of work, especially since the java file references lots of resources which also don't exist.

Surely I'm missing something and there's a quick and easy way to get this up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pointing to the single java file. It seems that that file is from this repository: https://github.com/kesenhoo/AndroidApiDemo

You can clone it and import to Android Studio. It is a complete project and will run your class correctly

Comment: When the Android SDK is downloaded, all that comes is that single .java file (if that SDK directory is browsed, its full of lots of other unrelated demo .java files, all of which are on there own i.e. not in a project). I don't  know where the project comes from on github, but I'll give it a whirl anyway, thanks.